# How to fit birt report in one single page for PDF

Tags: birt

I'm very new to BIRT report. Right now my task is fit whole BIRT report in one single page while view as PDF.

I have been search a solution for it but couldn't get any suggestion.

Please help me with some suggestion.

Thanks in advance.